# Rails doesn't receive http post request parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-post

I'm working on a simple one-page website on Ruby on Rails that has a 'Contact Us' form. It has 3 fields - name, e-mail and text -, and a submit button. In theory, after filling up these forms and clicking the button, the user will receive an email with the confirmation of the request. The controller basically has only one method that writes the data in the DB and after successful saving sends an email.

The problem is that the controller doesn't receive the parameters(name, email and text) and raises an exception: `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: application)`

I'm sure that the data is sent. Here's the log:

```
Started POST "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-23 20:25:08 +0300
Processing by ApplicationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"name"=>"Foo Bar", "email"=>"foobar@example.com", "text"=>"qwerqwepoiqtwporihtqwojbr[sdfzxc"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 381609ms
```

Source code of the controller:

```
class ApplicationsController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'text/html' }

  def new
    @request = Application.new
  end

  def create
    @request = Application.new(application_params)
    if @request.save
      ApplicationMailer.request_confirmation(@request).deliver_now
      flash[:info] = 'Your application has been registered! Check your e-mail!'
    else
      flash[:alert] = 'Oops! Your application was not registered!'
    end
  end

  private
    def application_params
      params.require(:application).permit(:name, :email, :text)
    end
end
```

Source code of the Application model:

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save{
    self.email.downcase!
  }
  validates(:name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 })
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates(:email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255},
            format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX})
  validates(:text, presence: true)
end
```

Does anybody have any idea where is the problem and how to solve it?

Thank you in advance.

UPD:
Form code:

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal col-md-8" name="application" id="applyForm">
        <div class="row" id="credentials">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="input-group form-group" id="full_name">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="input-group form-group" id="email">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
              <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="email">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="comment-area">
          <div class="col-sm-12" id="comment">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="text" rows="10" placeholder="Please describe your system" id="text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="submit-button">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>Send message</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you include your form code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `params` are not coming from `application`, for a quick fix just change `application_params` to below

```
def application_params
  params.permit(:name, :email, :text)
end
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I'm just learning Rails. Could you please explain why the `params` are not coming from `application`? Form code is in UPD to the post.

Comment: @mityakoval Its because your `attributes` are not wrapped inside the `form object`. For example this `<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="name">` should be `<input type="text" name="application[name]" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="name">`.

Comment: @mityakoval I would prefer rails `form_for` than `HTML form`

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks. I used rails `form_for` tag before for not so complicated forms. This one has too many not usual attributes. But I will definitely replace it with rails tag. Thank you!